# How can I loop over Tables which contain specific characters in their AOT name and delete the data?

Tags: x++, axapta

I want to loop over a few tables where the name (aotName) begins with 'HbcCka', finally I want to delete all data from the tables.

Now I need a logic to empty the tables. How can I achieve this?

UPDATED:

```
static void tstDeleteForecastingData(Args _args)
{
    Dictionary  dictionary = new Dictionary();
    int         i;
    SysDictTable    dictTable;
    ;
    for (i=1 ; i<=dictionary.tableCnt() ; i++)
    {
        if (strScan(tableid2name(dictionary.tableCnt2Id(i)), "HbcCka", 1, strLen(dictionary.tableName(i))))
        {
            info(strfmt('%1;%2', dictionary.tableCnt2Id(i), tableid2name( dictionary.tableCnt2Id(i) )));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truncate the tables in **all** companies?

Use System Administration\Periodic\Databases\SQL Administration, mark the tables then choose Table actions\Truncate.

Or make a class with a server main method:

```
ClassDeclaration tstDeleteForecastingData
{
}
static server void main(Args _args)
{
    Dictionary  dictionary = new Dictionary();
    int         i;
    for (i=1 ; i<=dictionary.tableCnt() ; i++)
    {
        if (strScan(tableid2name(dictionary.tableCnt2Id(i)), "HbcCka", 1, 99)))
        {
            info(strfmt('%1;%2', dictionary.tableCnt2Id(i), tableid2name( dictionary.tableCnt2Id(i) )));
            new SqlDataDictionaryPermission(methodstr(SqlDataDictionary, tableTruncate)).assert();
            new SqlDataDictionary().tableTruncate(dictionary.tableCnt2Id(i), false);
            CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
        }
    }

}
```

If **only** in current company:

```
Common table = new DictTable(<tableId>).makeRecord();
table.skipDeleteMethod(true);
table.skipDeleteAction(true);
delete_from table;
```

Comment: It was only for the current company, so I implemented the second option. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To speed things up, you could use the stored procedure sp_msforeachtable to loop tables in the database (with a check on the table names) and just write your delete statement to delete records where the dataAreaId is the one you want.

Something like this can be use to delete the tables starting with HbcCka in the CEU company:

```
exec sp_msforeachtable '
        if "?" like "HbcCka%"
        delete from ? where DataAreaId = "CEU"
        '
```

Comment: The speed will be the same, as X++ `delete_from table` will translate to the same SQL.