# To read all the table names and properties from AOT dynamically using c# or X++ language

Tags: c#, axapta, x++

I want to read all the table names and properties from D365 operation AOT dynamically (c# or X++). How can i read AOT tables names and properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over any table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304657/iterating-over-any-table)

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways:

1. legacy axapta way: use the Dictionary class from x++ code. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dictionary.aspx
2. d365fo way: use Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Metadata.Storage.MetadataProvider. See https://gist.github.com/mazzy-ax/4d4d06ec2fddd885b67527623467aee8 or https://gist.github.com/mazzy-ax/292f2ce1a8e79c39d1fc753bfca9c529 for extern application
3. (not recommended) xml-file exploring in the C:\AOSService\PackagesLocalDirectory\